# Getting "Cannot read property 'pickAlgorithm' of null" error in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, netlify, netlify-cli

I get an error when running npm install.

```js
npm install -g netlify-cli
```

The error is:

```js
npm WARN deprecated statsd-client@0.4.7: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.     
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'pickAlgorithm')    

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-09-13T23_14_47_800Z-debug-0.log
```

Environment:

OS: Windows 10 |
reactjs: 18.2.0 |
Node: 16.17.0 |
npm: 8.17.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Then set npm registry

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

And finally install packages

```
npm install
```

This worked for me although I have found other users getting it to work by simply clearing the cache and then installing packages directly without configuring the registry

Comment: that fixed it. The error is not showing anymore and I installed the cli, thank you for your help